# if $\mid f(x)\mid<1$ then $\mid f'(x)\mid<1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

I am wondering, if $\mid f(x)\mid<1$ then $\mid f'(x)\mid<1$.

Is this true? I can not find counter example.

Comment: Think about rapidly oscillating functions.

Comment: $\sin (x^2)$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Note even without counterexample this doesn't seem to be true since it trying to imply that if a function is bounded by 1 that its "steepness is also bounded

Comment: f(x)=2x in the interval (-1/2,1/2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(4x).$$